# My Table is not updating its data with states and useEffect()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

I've written a file which contains a Table that should display codes when there are pushed inside the array codes with prop name code (e.x. "848389494")

now every time the function addNewCode is called it should update the _codeData Object but it's not possible because its an outer scouped function. i cant move it inside ScannerResultTable because addNewCode should be able to be exported and used in another Component.

but i dont know how its not possible to useEffect and keep track on "codes" but it wont allow it because it's an outerscouped var.

thanks for your help-

```
const codes = []

export function addNewCode(value){
    codes.push({ code: value });
}

export default function ScannerResultTable() {
    const [_codeData, setCodeData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Hi im rendering");
        setCodeData(codes);
      }, []);

    const [tableData, setTableData] = useState(_codeData);
```

Comment: Where in your app is addNewCode()? It looks like what you should be doing is passing _codeData as a prop into ScannerResultTable().

Comment: If the code variable is to be used in multiple components, then, You can put the codes as a State within Context, have addNew function or even better use a Reducer. https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: Another way of doing so would be using a State management Library like `Redux`. https://redux-toolkit.js.org/introduction/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a globally defined variable `codes`, you can make use of React context and make the `codes` a state in some parent components and pass down the utility function to update the `codes` to the child components that are gonna update it.

More details on how to use react context can be found [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)